# Variable table_name in from section

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created loop in oracle because i want to count records from all tabes in database.

What is wrong in my code?

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN(SELECT table_name
         FROM   all_tables) LOOP
    dbms_output.Put_line(i.table_name);

    FOR j IN(SELECT Count(1) AS counter
             FROM   i.tab_name) LOOP
        dbms_output.Put_line(j.counter);
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use table names from variable. You must use dynamic SQL, for example like this:

```
DECLARE
   counter NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR i IN (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables) LOOP
    dbms_output.Put_line(i.table_name);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT Count(1) FROM ' || i.table_name INTO counter;
    dbms_output.Put_line(counter);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: @Grzegorzko error inherited from *your* code - now it works